# I have a toshiba laptop i am trying to figure how old it is the serial numbers are XA365492K

Tags: laptop, battery

I need help figuring out how old my toshiba laptop is. Serial number is xa365492k.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.dynabook.com/ shows you have a [Satellite Pro L670-EZ1711](https://support.dynabook.com/support/modelHome?freeText=xa365492k). Battery issues are explained on [pages 26-32](https://support.dynabook.com/support/staticContentDetail?contentId=2754028&isFromTOCLink=false). More detailed manuals may be available for this 2010 machine at https://www.manualslib.com/products/Toshiba-L670-Ez1711-448582.html